# Bootstrap form does not submit on click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

The form should get submitted and give a success message if validation turns out okay. But it rather gets stuck on submit and no action happens. Please find my HTML PHP AND JS Code below.I have a database created on the Xampp server.
I am new to bootstrap and ajax. Please help! I keep getting stuck on the submit button every now and then

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.min.css">

    <title> Registration Form </title>

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="images/apple-icon-57x57.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="images/apple-icon-60x60.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="images/apple-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="images/apple-icon-76x76.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="images/apple-icon-114x114.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="images/apple-icon-120x120.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="images/apple-icon-144x144.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="images/apple-icon-152x152.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="images/apple-icon-180x180.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="images/android-icon-192x192.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="images/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="images/favicon-96x96.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="images/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="images/manifest.json">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="images/ms-icon-144x144.png">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">






</head>

<body>


<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header"><img class="logoPicture" src="images/nyu_long_white.png" alt="" height="42px" width="246px">
                <h2 class="ospHeader">The Office of Sponsored Programs</h2>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-me" aria-expanded="false"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-me">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="http://www.nyu.edu/" class="navbar-link">NYU Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.nyu.edu/about/" class="navbar-link">About NYU</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.nyu.edu/search/" class="navbar-link">Search NYU</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="http://www.nyu.edu/research/resources-and-support-offices/getting-started-withyourresearch/office-of-sponsored-programs/about.html" class="navbar-link">About OSP</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.nyu.edu/research/resources-and-support-offices/getting-started-withyourresearch.html" class="navbar-link">Funding Opps</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.nyu.edu/research/resources-and-support-offices/getting-started-withyourresearch/office-of-sponsored-programs/policies.html" class="navbar-link">Policies &amp; Procedures</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.nyu.edu/research/resources-and-support-offices/getting-started-withyourresearch/office-of-sponsored-programs/forms-guides.html" class="navbar-link">Proposals</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container local-nav-links">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="https://www.nyu.edu/osp/">OSP Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://www.nyu.edu/research/resources-and-support-offices/getting-started-withyourresearch/registration-for-electronic-submissions.html">Registration for Electionic Submission</a>
            </li>
            <li class="active">Registration</li>
        </ol>









<div class="container">

<form class="well form-horizontal" method="POST" action="js/formdata.php" id="contact_form" >

<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend><center><h2><b> Cayuse Registration Form</b></h2></center></legend><br>

<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">First Name</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
  <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  <input  name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control"  type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" >Last Name</label> 
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  <input name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control"  type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->

       <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
  <input name="email" placeholder="E-Mail Address" class="form-control"  type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  <!-- Text input-->

  <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" >NetID<br>
(See back of NYU Card)</label> 
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  <input name="netid" placeholder="NetID" class="form-control"  type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->

  <div class="form-group"> 
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Department / Office</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 selectContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span>
    <select name="department" class="form-control selectpicker">
      <option value="">Select your Department/Office</option>
      <option>NYU - New York University (NYU)   (0)</option>
<option>PROVOST - Office of the Provost (PROVOST)   (08000)</option>
<option>PROVOST - Faculty Resource Network (FRN)   (03020)</option>
<option>PROVOST - Asian/Pacific/American Institute (A / P / A)   (03055)</option>
<option>PROVOST - Institute of African-American Affairs (IAAA)   (03400)</option>
<option>PROVOST - NYU Entrepreneurial Institute   (08014)</option>
<option>PROVOST - Institute for Public Knowledge (IPK)   (08021)</option>
<option>PROVOST - Center for the Study of Gender & Sexuality   (08022)</option>
<option>PROVOST - Center for Dialogues: Islamic World - US - The West   (08023)</option>
<option>PROVOST - Institute on the Arts and Civic Dialogue   (08025)</option>
<option>PROVOST - Hemispheric Institute   (08026)</option>
<option>PROVOST - Center for the Study of Transformative Life   (08027)</option>
<option>PROVOST - Africa House   (08063)</option>
<option>PROVOST - China House   (08064)</option>
<option>PROVOST - Development Research Institute (DRI)   (08051)</option>
<option>PROVOST - HEOP   (57950)</option>
<option>PROVOST - C-STEP   (57951)</option>
<option>PROVOST - STEP   (57952)</option>
<option>PROVOST - BEST   (57953)</option>
<option>PROVOST - Center on Violence and Recovery   (08000A)</option>
<option>PROVOST - Scholars at Risk   (08032)</option>
<option>CUSP - Center for Urban Science + Progress (CUSP)   (64000)</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

  <!-- Text input-->

   <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" >Job Title</label> 
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  <input name="jobtitle" placeholder="Job Title" class="form-control"  type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Contact No.</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
  <input name="contact_no" placeholder="(639)" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  <!-- Text input-->

  <div class="form-group"> 
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Degree Type<br>(Completed)</label>

    <div class="col-md-4 selectContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span>
    <select name="degreetype" class="form-control selectpicker">
      <option>Select your Degree type</option>
      <option>Associate in Arts</option>
<option>Associate in Science</option>
<option>Bachelor of Arts</option>
<option>Bachelor of Agriculture</option>
<option>Bachelor of Architecture</option>


      </td>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

  <!-- Text input-->

  <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Degree Year</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  <input name="degreeyear" placeholder="YYYY" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Select Basic -->

   <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">System</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
   <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" id="cayuse" name="system">Cayuse
    </label><br>
       <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" id="irb" name= "system">Cayuse IRB
    </label><br>
       <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" id="fastlane" name="system">NSF FastLane
    </label><br>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" id="nihcommons" name= "system">eRA Commmons
    </label>

      </div>
  </div>
</div> 



<!-- Success message -->


<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>

  <div class="col-md-4"><br>
    &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit"  value="submit" > Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
</div>

 &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
<div class="footer navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class="container">

                <div class="row">
                    <p class="eResearchHelp text-right"><a href="mailtp:eResearch.help@nyu.edu">Email: eResearch.help@nyu.edu</a> with suggestions about the website.</p>
                </div>
            </div>


    </div>








    </div><!-- /.container -->
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.4.5/js/bootstrapvalidator.min.js'></script>

    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
    <?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','password','OSP');

if (!$conn) {
     echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
     echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
     echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
     exit;
    }


if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$first_name=$_POST['first_name'];
$last_name=$_POST['last_name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$netid=$_POST['netid'];
$department=$_POST['department'];
$jobtitle=$_POST['jobtitle'];
$contact_no=$_POST['contact_no'];
$degreetype=$_POST['degreetype'];
$degreeyear=$_POST['degreeyear'];
$cayuse = $_POST["RegisterCAY"];
$irb = $_POST["RegisterIRB"];
$fastlane = $_POST["RegisterNSF"];
$nihcommons = $_POST["RegisterNIH"];




 $query = "INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, email, netid, department, jobtitle, contact_no, degreetype, degreeyear,system) VALUES
  ('".$first_name."', '".$last_name."', '".$email."', '".$netid."', '".$department."', '".$jobtitle."', $contact_no ,'".$degreetype."', $degreeyear,'".$system."')";
        $sql = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    $subject = "Electronic Registration: ".$FirstName." ".$LastName;
    $message = "Please register ".$FirstName." ".$MiddleInitial." ".$LastName." ".$EmailAddress." ".$NetID." ".$PhoneNumber." ".$FaxNumber." ".$Department." ".$Title." ".$DegreeType." for the following:\n";
    if ($RegisterCAY) {$message = $message."Cayuse.\n";}
    if ($RegisterIRB) {$message = $message."Cayuse IRB.\n";}
    if ($RegisterNSF) {$message = $message."NSF FastLane.\n";}
    if ($RegisterNIH) {$message = $message."NIH eRA Commons.\n";}

    $headers = "From: Registration for Electronic Submissions System <pc@nyu.edu>\n";
    mail("pbc@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $headers);    



if(!$sql)
{

    echo" Error:".mysqli_error($conn);

}

else{
    echo "Thank you";
}

}

?>
```

JS

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contact_form').bootstrapValidator({
        // To use feedback icons, ensure that you use Bootstrap v3.1.0 or later
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            first_name: {
                validators: {
                        stringLength: {
                        min: 2,
                    },
                        notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please enter your First Name'
                    }
                }
            },

             last_name: {
                validators: {
                     stringLength: {
                        min: 2,
                    },
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please enter your Last Name'
                    }
                }
            },

            email: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please enter your Email Address'
                    },

                   regexp: {


                           regexp: '^[^@\\s]+@([^@\\s]+\\.)+[^@\\s]+$',
                               message: 'The value is not a valid email address'


                },
                }

            },


           netid: {
                validators: {
                  stringCase: {
                        message: 'The net ID must be in lowercase',
                        'case': 'lower',
                  },

                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please enter your NETID.'
                     }


                }

            },


          department: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please select your Department'
                    }
                }
            },   

          jobtitle: {
                validators: {
                     stringLength: {
                        min: 3,
                    },
                    notEmpty: {

                        message: 'Please enter your title'
                    }
                }
            },









       degreeyear: {
                validators: {

                    stringLength: {
                        min: 4,
                        max:4,
                    },
                    notEmpty: {

                        message: 'Please enter your Degree Year'
                    }
                }
            },       


                }
            }

         )


    .on('sucess.form.bv',function(e){
        $('#contact_form').on('submit',function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({


                type: 'post',
                url:'js/formdata.php',
                data: $('#contact_form').serialize(),
                success:function(){

                    alert('Form Submitted');
                }








            });
    });
});

});
```

Comment: to begin with, missed the # in the selecor of `$('contact_form').on('submit',function(e) {`, maybe more did not see it.

Comment: Hi , thanks for pointing it out. When I fixed it, it gives me this error below:   jquery.js (404 not found) It takes me to the line :                                     
 try {
     // Do send the request (this may raise an exception)
     xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );

Comment: Update your question with the new error. It is not showing up here in comments.

Comment: Hi, I updated it with the new error I see but the issue still persists.

Comment: the error messages are located in the console tab of the dev tools you opened, the screenshot is a good idea, unfortunately not that tab (not now).

Comment: Hi the issue is now fixed , but I see there is some problem in my ajax function since it's getting entered twice in the database. When the form is blank and I click submit, it gives me a success message which it should not

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the `if (isset($_POST[‘submit’]))` part. Instead of using that, try `if (isset($_POST[‘last_name’], $_POST[‘first_name’]))` (write all the post variables there) since I cannot see where is the button which names submit
Also, you also missed the `#` selector in the `$(‘contact_form’).serialize();`. Then try and comment if there is something else

Comment: Hi, there is a new error which I am facing which I edited in the question. Do you think you can help me with it?

Comment: @PriyankaGundania, can you post here a screenshot please? It would be good. But first, have you tried to change what I said?

Comment: @PriyankaGundania, wait, I found the problem here, have you included the jquery file (I mean the original jquery from JQUERY organization, not from BOOTSTRAP) in the HTML document? In the code above, I cannot see it anywhere. Make sure you include it before BOOTSTRAP JQUERY.

Comment: Hi Brian, I am not sure which jquery file are you talking about.